# Send update command to previous activity

Tags: android

I have 2 activities A and B
activity A contains a button to call activity B and A also contains a listview.
activity B contains some checkboxes and a close Button
After I click to close activity B I would like to update activity A's listview. What method do you think is good for me to follow now ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve your functionality, you need to launch activity `B` using [.startActivityForResult()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29) and override the [onActivityResult()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onActivityResult%28int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent%29) method to do all the processing you need to do when `B` has been terminated.